# Vb.Net DataView Search Issue In RowFilter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, search, datarow, dataview

I am working with VB.Net and there is a scenario in application is that, we search from dataview by setting `DataView.RowFilter = "some search text"`  property, we have a scenario in which there is an apostrophe sign `(')` in search string, we replace it with `['']`. but this will never give result ever even the rowset containing `['']` symbols in row set.

Further more I have played with the search criteria value like `'%SearchText[%'` , it says invalid pattern, I canot change the logic back in Application rather to fix it in StoredProcedure so it may find the best result.

Following is the Search Text = `"Hello Kitty’s Friendship"` and below are two rows in DataView Object.`FormattedName = Column`

```
Hello Kitty['']s Friendship Bouquet
Hello Kitty['']s Friendship Bouquet Mango
```

And Following is the code:

```
Dim strLocal As String = "FormattedName Like'%Hello Kitty['']s Friendship Bouq'%"
dvProducts.RowFilter = strLocal
```

`FormattedName`is the column on which we apply search.

Somebody please suggest.

Comment: which version of .net you are using ??

Comment: Visual Studio 2010. Net 3.5

Comment: Then you can use `LINQ`, something like this - `dvProducts.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Field<string>("FormattedName").Contains("Hello Kitty")).ToList();`. This is c# code. You need to convert into vb.net.

Comment: But,  I can't change in executable,  due to thousands of deployments of the exercise. Unless the next release.

Comment: Ok, then try this - `dvProducts.RowFilter = String.Format("FormattedName LIKE '%{0}%'", "Hello Kitty's Friendship".Replace("'", "''"));`

Comment: Are you just wanting to replace a part of a string in sql, then use replace...

Comment: @Codexer I have done that but the thing is that string containing ’[]’ symbols wont be searched.